# Cannot access cookies in Laravel when request is from external API

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

TLDR Why can't I access a cookie that was set on my website, from the users browser when the request to my websites endpoint is from another website.

I'm building a site that sells affiliate products. When a user clicks on an affiliate product, before redirecting them to the affiliates website, I store a cookie that states the user has clicked the product.

If they purchase the product on the affiliate site, there is an image tag on the affiliate websites thank you page which calls an endpoint on our website. Here I can then log the sale in our database.

In our endpoint I'm trying get that cookie back from the users browser, but for some reason `$response->cookie()` is empty and it's also missing from `Cookie::get()`. I can't figure out why this is happening? Surely after I set the cookie for the user and then they go to the other website, the user is making a get request back to my site where I should be able to get their cookies from their browser, no?

This certainly isn't a good way of handling this functionality by any means, but I'm restricted by the affiliate website who doesn't have an API, but were happy to place our endpoint in a hidden image tag on the thankyou page.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please post the `Set-Cookie` header and information from the developer console and network tab to allow tracing at which point the cookie is accessible and when it isn't. Reading the cookie from `$response` is also weird, do you mean `$request`?

Comment: Sorry @DanielW. I did mean $request (`Illuminate\Http\Request`)!

Comment: Please add more debug information